# How do I share my Game Maker games?

Tags: game-maker, export

I'm using GameMaker Studio and I want to put my game on my website.

I need help with saving a game in a exe file or anything that will make my game to open normally. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can export to Windows PC and Mac OS with the free edition of Game Maker (other export types, [like web or mobile, require paid versions](http://www.yoyogames.com/studio)).

To create an executable, just open your project, select [File->Create executable](http://game-maker.wikidot.com/create-executable)

The latest version of Game Maker Studio (1.2), the option you want is "Create Application":

[image]

From there, you can save it as an installer, a compiled exe or a zip.

[image]

In this case, you could use the "Single runtime executable" and distribute that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share your games online after making the exe, you can make an account on Gamejolt and upload it there.